# What is a deep and scratchy voice called?

Tags: genre, vocal-styles

In this cover of Tom’s Diner by AnnenMayKantereit x Giant Rooks

Does the type of voice of the deep and scratchy guy have a name or a genre it’s usually associated with?

Answer (score 1):

That kind of low male voice is called 'bass', the scratchiness is just bad vocal technique. You'll very often find a bass in any kind of vocal harmony group. See [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10178/example-of-a-pop-song-where-a-male-singer-sings-f2-g2/10217#10217=) for more examples of this type of voice.